# Assembly x86 architecture Game programming jumping physics

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I am trying to program street fighter in assembly x86 and i get some problems with the jumping of the player. I want him to jump with a constant velocity to a certain height and than to fall realisticly with an acceleration. I know that it's only a physics problem but i get some problems with the first part of the movement: the player "teleports" to that maximal height. It is not fluid like i want, i want to see the whole movement and not only a teleportation from A to B. Here is the code that i'm actually using`enter code here`:

```
 PROC Jump1 USES eax     
   mov eax, [y]
   add eax, -1
   mov [y], eax    
   ret
 ENDP Jump1

 PROC Jump USES eax, ebx, ecx, edx   
 @@j:
   mov eax, [y]
   cmp eax, [ymax]
   jne @@p
   jmp @@ret     
 @@p:
   call Jump1
   jmp @@j  
 @@ret:
   ret
 ENDP Jump
```

So I was wondering: how I would do this to get a smoother movement?

Comment: This is really independent of it being in assembly or not, it's more of a general physics in games question.

Comment: If you don't display each intermediate state and put some kind of delay in between them then of course you're going to have the kind of behavior you describe.

Comment: Set the player's state to "Jumping", step 0. Then every screen update move the player one step, incrementing the step counter each time. This works best if you have a constant screen update rate.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't teleport him, moves him just by -1 (under/above `ymax`) or let him stay on `ymax`. So the "teleportation" happens elsewhere, either you overwrite `[y]` by accident with max value, or you don't draw intermediate steps between calls of `Jump` and display only the final state where `y` is already equal `ymax` (or you draw them too fast, so you see only the last one on display). Anyway all of this should be clearly visible in debugger, so are you trying to code a game without debugger? If yes, then good luck, you will need lot of it in 2017 and 2018...